# list of dictionaries write to a file jusing json decoder encoder

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime

class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj,datetime.date):

            obj= datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d ")

        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):

            obj= datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.time):

            obj = datetime.time.strftime(obj,"%H:%M:%S")

        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):

            obj = float(obj)
        else:
            obj = super(MyEncoder1, self).default(obj)
        return obj

json_array = dumps(data,cls=MyEncoder1)

with open(filename,"a") as fobj:

    for index in range(0,len(json_array)):
        fobj.write(json_array[index])
    fobj.close()
```

I am getting an error`AttributeError("module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'",)`

Answer (score 1):

First thing: you want `strftime()` here not `strptime()` (`strptime()` is for parsing a datetime string to a datetime.datetime object).

Second point: `strftime()` is a method of `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` objects, so the correct call is

```
obj = obj.strftime(your_format_string_here)
```